# ¿Cómo validar el mínimo de archivos de un fileupload en primeface?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estoy usando primefaces y tengo el caso de que necesito subir solo 2 archivos, ni más ni menos ... en el fileLimit puedo controlar que no suba más, pero ¿cómo puedo validar que no suba menos de 2?
Gracias.

---

```
<h:form>
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
              multiple="true" update="messages" sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="3" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />

<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: No tiene ninguna propiedad que haga eso

Comment: Crea dos inputs que no sean `multiple` y hazlos ambos `required`. Así además le quedará más claro al usuario.

Comment: Hola, no me sirve en este caso para los requerimientos del cliente. No se puede validar el mínimo así como se valida el máximo?

Comment: Otra razón por la que no me sirve colocar dos que no sean multiples, es por que la persona puede enviar uno con el upload y cerrar el formulario (este no tiene botón enviar) es un formulario solo para enviar el archivo.